# Using Ltm package to calclate 3PL some lines of data seem to go missing

Tags: r, psychometrics, item-response-theory

I am hoping someone can help with the following:

1. I have been trying to use the ltm package in R to get person fit estimates using a 3PL model.  The problem I have been having is that I start off with 4947 response patterns (dichotomous) but when I run `tpm()` I end up with 4851 ability estimates and 4851 person fit estimates.  I tried with another data set and ended up with a similar problem.

   Here is the line of code I've used---`gr3` is the dataset with 4947 lines of data containing zeroes and ones.

   ```
    threePL <- tpm(gr3, na.action = NULL)
   ```
2. In addition, in order to run the 3PL model, I have to get rid of the person IDs, but I would like to retain the person IDs so that I can accurately map the ability and person fit estimates onto the right person.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @nikki0111. Are you thinking of this as a conceptual statistics / psychometrics question, or an R programming assistance question? I'm not sure, but I wonder if it is the latter. If so, this question would be off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). It *could* be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), but it would need to have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/).

Comment: If you want help with the *ideas*, please edit to clarify; if you just want help w/ the *coding*, add a reproducible example & flag your Q. We can migrate it for you. (*Please don't cross-post, though.*)

Answer (score 1):

rows that have the same response pattern will be combined to save space, try,

```
    threePL <- tpm(gr3, na.action = NULL)
    ability.est <- factor.scores(threePL, gr3)
```

and you will get the ability estimates that correspond to each of your rows.